# Can I use expo packages or libraries in bare work flow, I used some permissions and

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-permissions

Can I use expo packages or libraries in bare work flow,  I used some permissions and apploading these type of blah blah packages in my expo project and ejected to bare work flow, after running react-native run-android getting error expo require expo sdk to run

Answer (score 0):

what SDK version were you on when you ejected? if you are not using the latest sdk version (37 at the time of writing), i would recommend reverting the eject and running `expo upgrade` then ejecting again. the process is a lot smoother in 37 and will continue to get better over time.

you can absolutely use nearly every library in bare react native apps! but you can't use everything that's available from the `expo` package itself, we're almost done removing everything from there but they may be some leftovers. check your project to see what you're importing `from "expo"` and replace those with alternatives. imports `from "expo-*"` will work great.